# news website with php and links using rewrite rules

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have created a news website where everything is based on php and mysql.

I have noticed that on other websites, whenever you click on a new article the link opens as:
`http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2012/09/space-shuttle-endeavour-lands-in-los-angeles/`

In my website, I have a page named `viewer.php` and this page connects to the database.
When you click on a news in my site, you see something like this in link bar:
`www.example.com/viewer.php?ne_id=14`

`ne_id` in my news table set specific number for a news like 14.
All of the news (title, content and so on) is saved in the database.

How does that site work (wired.com)? How do I create a site like that?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) if you are using Apache. Alternatively, if you are using IIS you might want to look at [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

But almost any server software supports this kind of functionality. Its generally called URL rewriting.

Hope this helps